# Duplicate row and change values basing on values from other table in Oracle SQL

Tags: sql, oracle, duplicates

I have two tables in Oracle SQL: **owners** and **groups**.

**owners** table:

| GUID | LOGIN | NAME |
| --- | --- | --- |
| aa1 | Adam | Altos |
| bbb | Bart | Berry |
| cc1 | Carl | Cole |
| aa2 | Adam | Altos |
| eee | Elle | Eyew |
| cc2 | Carl | Cole |

**groups** table:

| OWNER_GUID | USER_GUID |
| --- | --- |
| cc1 | CCCCCCCCC |
| gh1 | gfdsagfdg |
| iop | seyhrfdfs |
| aa1 | AAAAAAAAA |
| cvb | 12sgdjku2 |

In **owners** table there are rows which have the same login and name (login, name, guid(s) listed below):

- Adam, Altos, aa1 and aa2
- Carl, Cole, cc1 and cc2

Currently in **groups** table there are only rows corresponding to cc1 and aa1 from **owners** table. What I want to achieve:

If in **groups** table there is a GUID in `OWNER_GUID` column, which login and name *pair* are duplicated in **owners** table then an insert should be done to **groups** table with GUID of the item, which for now is missing in **groups** and `USER_GUID` value should be the same as the item which exists in this table have.

It may be a little confusing so I will give you an example:

1. In **owners** table  login, name pair Adam, Altos is duplicated and these rows have guids aa1 and aa2.
2. In **groups** currently there is a row with `OWNER_GUID` value equal to aa1 - aa2 is missing. The value in `USER_GUID` of this row is `AAAAAAAAA`.
3. Owner GUID aa2 should be inserted to **groups** as `OWNER_GUID` with `USER_GUID` value the same which aa1 has - AAAAAAAAA.
4. There is another duplicated login, name pair - Carl, Cole for cc1 and cc2 guids in **owners** table so eventually two inserts should be done. Manually we can write it in below manner:

```sql
INSERT INTO groups(owner_guid, user_guid) VALUES ('aa2', 'AAAAAAAAA');
INSERT INTO groups(owner_guid, user_guid) VALUES ('cc2', 'CCCCCCCCC');
```

Could you help me with finding such a command/query? If you need a playgroud I prepared a SQLFiddle with described tables: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/325a96

Here is also commands to create the table if something with the Fiddle will go wrong: https://pastebin.com/BGhhk34Y

I am able to select guids that should be inserted to **groups**, but I cannot assign for them a proper values. I don't have idea how extract proper `USER_GUID` from **groups** and assign them to these values.

```sql
SELECT guid FROM owners WHERE (login, name) IN
(SELECT login, name FROM owners
GROUP BY login, name HAVING COUNT(*) > 1)
AND guid NOT IN (SELECT owner_guid FROM groups);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I hope I understood you correctly.
You can use a combination of a `SELECT` statement and an `INSERT INTO SELECT` statement.

[Try this in SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/325a96/10)

Example:

```
INSERT INTO groups (OWNER_GUID, USER_GUID)
SELECT o.GUID, g.USER_GUID
FROM owners o
JOIN groups g ON o.LOGIN = (SELECT o2.LOGIN FROM owners o2 WHERE o2.GUID = g.OWNER_GUID)
             AND o.NAME = (SELECT o3.NAME FROM owners o3 WHERE o3.GUID = g.OWNER_GUID)
WHERE o.GUID NOT IN (SELECT OWNER_GUID FROM groups);
```

Answer (score 2):

Another option is to use [WITH Clause : Subquery Factoring in Oracle](https://oracle-base.com/articles/misc/with-clause).

Start by finding duplicate pairs , in the second subquery we find the missing `OWNER_GUID   USER_GUID`

```
with duplicates as  (
  SELECT GUID,
         LOGIN,
         NAME, 
         COUNT(*) OVER(PARTITION BY LOGIN,NAME) cnt
  FROM owners
), user_guid_values as (
  select GUID ,
         OWNER_GUID,
         USER_GUID,
         concat(LOGIN,NAME) as log_name
  from duplicates d  
  left join groups g  on g.OWNER_GUID=d.GUID
  where d.cnt>1
) select * from user_guid_values;
```

Result ,

```
GUID    OWNER_GUID    USER_GUID  LOG_NAME
cc1       cc1         CCCCCCCCC   CarlCole
aa1       aa1         AAAAAAAAA   AdamAltos
aa2       null         null       AdamAltos
cc2       null         null       CarlCole
```

Self join the second subquery table ,

```
with duplicates as  (
  SELECT GUID,
         LOGIN,
         NAME, 
         COUNT(*) OVER(PARTITION BY LOGIN,NAME) cnt
  FROM owners
), user_guid_values as (
  select GUID ,
         OWNER_GUID,
         USER_GUID,
         concat(LOGIN,NAME) as log_name
  from duplicates d  
  left join groups g  on g.OWNER_GUID=d.GUID
  where d.cnt>1
)
select ugd.GUID as OWNER_GUID,
       ugd1.USER_GUID as USER_GUID
from user_guid_values ugd 
inner join  user_guid_values ugd1 on ugd.LOG_NAME=ugd1.LOG_NAME 
where ugd.OWNER_GUID is null
and ugd1.USER_GUID is not null  ;
```

Result

```
OWNER_GUID  USER_GUID
  cc2       CCCCCCCCC
  aa2       AAAAAAAAA
```

Final step, insert above missing values

```
INSERT INTO groups( OWNER_GUID, USER_GUID)
with duplicates as  (
  SELECT GUID,
         LOGIN,
         NAME, 
         COUNT(*) OVER(PARTITION BY LOGIN,NAME) cnt
  FROM owners
), user_guid_values as (
  select GUID ,
         OWNER_GUID,
         USER_GUID,
         concat(LOGIN,NAME) as log_name
  from duplicates d  
  left join groups g  on g.OWNER_GUID=d.GUID
  where d.cnt>1
)
select ugd.GUID as OWNER_GUID,
       ugd1.USER_GUID as USER_GUID
from user_guid_values ugd 
inner join  user_guid_values ugd1 on ugd.LOG_NAME=ugd1.LOG_NAME 
where ugd.OWNER_GUID is null
and ugd1.USER_GUID is not null  ;
```

See example [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/xsVwUijo)

Comment: Thank you very much, your code also works, but for now is too complicated for me. It seems that lack of knowledge about Joins and With clause was the thing that stopped me from getting to the solution on my own. It would be nice to fill these gaps in order to be able to construct queries like yours.

Comment: @dtm_ window function will make your life easier. They are easy to use...you just need some practice